# Ставить ли запятую в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

**Основы единства были заложены в начале прошлого века после создания учебных заведений, Благотворительного общества(,) и особенно в ходе проведения съездов.**

Нужна ли запятая в скобках (предложение внутри сократил-упростил)? И почему?

Comment: А в каком именно месте "сократил-упростил"? Вполне возможно, что это повлияет на пунктуацию.

Comment: Убрал пояснения-определения (не обороты), а то очень трудно воспринимается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу так (упрощаем предложение):
Были заложены (когда?) **после создания** (чего?) заведений, общества и (когда?) **в ходе проведения**.

Имеем две группы однородных членов:
1 — после создания и в ходе проведения;
2 — заведений, общества.

"И особенно в ходе проведения съездов" не является присоединительным членом предложения, не содержит дополнительных разъяснений или замечаний (создание заведений и обществ — отдельно, ход проведения съездов — отдельно), поэтому запятую между однородными обстоятельствами не ставим (одиночный союз **и**).

[**особенно**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_511), наречие
Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
Если слово «особенно» начинает собой присоединительный оборот, содержащий дополнительные замечания или разъяснения, то оно обособляется вместе со всем оборотом.

Некоторые разъяснения по поводу пунктуации с "особенно" дает [**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20).
Думаю, что можно выделить "особенно" запятыми, если хочется подчеркнуть это слово, обратить на него внимание (см. вопрос № 288384).

Comment: @Рад, Вас что-то не устроило в моем ответе?

Comment: Наоборот, спасибо большое!